# Using dsget to get membership list

Tags: active-directory, command

I currently have a command script as such:

```
dsget user "*user details and domain details*" -memberof
```

This gets me the list of the groups that the user is part of. My problem is that it returns the results as the FQDN (CN=Group 1,OU=Server,OU=etc...)

How can I extract just the CN information into a list without all the extra parts please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure it's exactly what your looking for, but you can try to pipe the result in `dsget group` just asking for `samid`.

```
dsget user "*user details and domain details*" -memberof -expand | dsget group  -samid
```